# Wait for press Enter for third input

Tags: c

In this main method when i enter data for three test case,then in side for loop scanf for "data" variable wait for user press enter

```
int main()
{

    int test,n,k,data,rem;
    scanf("%d",&test);
    while(test--){
        //free(head);
        head=NULL;
        rear=NULL;
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&n);
        scanf("%d",&k);
        printf("\nk=%d\n",k);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d",&data);
            add(&head,data,&rear);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            rem=delete(&head);
            //printf("rem=%d\n",rem);
        }
        //printf("\nk=%d",k);
        //printf("%d ",test);
        display(head);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wait for return key by making use of `getline()` function..

Comment: 1) C does not support methods. And even in C++ `main` is just a function. 2) `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behaviour. Never `fflush` an input stream. Instead drop unused characters. 3) What is your **specific** problem? 4) See [ask].

Comment: where i use getline() @SMA

Comment: after your scanf...

Comment: All the inputs you have (in the partial code posted) use the `%d` format specifier, which ignores leading whitespace, so there should be no need to do any flushing.

Comment: scanf function not work in third time for variable "data" .It is waiting for user press enter. @Olaf

Comment: After adding getline() function it gives errar at compile time.

Comment: second input for number of element search @user3121023

Comment: inner loop iterate n times, two time work fine but third time wait  @user3121023

Comment: `stdin` is usually _line buffered_.  That is a keyboard/OS specific issue, not C.  C does not receive _any_ user input until the user presses <Enter>.  You need a platform specific function to not "wait for enter".  Else explain your problem clearly.